# LocationProvider - Detecting highly inaccurate/incorrect locations

Tags: android, gps, location

So I know you can use getAccuracy() to find the accuracy of a location but if you set up a cut off for the accuracy, can you prevent recording down one of those locations where it's hugely off mark of where the user is? Like if the user is still, most location updates cluster around his area but occasionally the location provider will hiccup and report the location as somewhere miles away.

Do these locations simply appear as "accurate" with getAccuracy? Or would they turn up as some insanely high getAccuracy() result? Programming a cut off point is easy enough but I was wondering if I would have to code extra checks such as if a location is way too different from the previous ones then it's a wayward one.

Comment: For those hiccups, getAccuracy() would return a big number, but the location could also be cached and rather old. IMHO the accuracy is sometimes given too much meaning - the age of the location also matters. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is not the only deciding factor here. You should also look at the age of the location, and the provider if you get it (the Google Play Services location doesn't tell you, but the original Android LocationManager does).

In fact, Google has some useful sample code for [maintaining a current best estimate](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate). I have used a variation of this to filter out wild jumps in incoming location data. Essentially a location is not even reported if it doesn't pass this gate.

Comment: I'm I'm only getting location reports from onLocationChanged, wouldn't that mean the location is never older than the last one? I'm using the FusedProvider yes. I always check the reported time (With getTime()) and as far as I know, it never returns an old location.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but I don't know for certain. But if the fused provider delivers you a cached location that originated from the network, before the GPS system wakes up, it makes sense that the cached location would have an older timestamp than the first GPS location.